# В чем проблема с кодом?

Tags: java

Почему-то при работе с мапой не находится ключ, который там должен быть. Вот код:

класс RealProfile

```
public class RealProfile {

    private String idRealProfile;
    private Gender gender;
    private Age age;
    private Income income;
    // getters & setters
}
```

А вот код:

```
    RealProfile rp =  new RealProfile();
    rp.setAge(Age.AGE1);
    rp.setGender(Gender.FEMALE);
    rp.setIncome(Income.A);

    RealProfile rp2 = new RealProfile();
    rp2.setAge(Age.AGE1);
    rp2.setGender(Gender.MALE);
    rp2.setIncome(Income.B);

    Map<RealProfile, ArrayList<ModelledProfile>> example = new HashMap<RealProfile, ArrayList<ModelledProfile>>();

    ArrayList<ModelledProfile> q = new ArrayList<ModelledProfile>();
   // Задаю Лист

    example.put(rp, q);
    example.put(rp2, q);

    RealProfile rp3 = new RealProfile();
    rp3.setAge(Age.AGE1);
    rp3.setGender(Gender.FEMALE);
    rp3.setIncome(Income.A);

    out.println(example.containsKey(rp3));
```

В rp3 лежит тоже самое, что и в rp, а метод contain выдает false. Почему?

---

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 2;
    hash = hash*5 + gender.toString().hashCode();
    hash = hash*5 + age.toString().hashCode();
    hash = hash*5 + income.toString().hashCode();
    return hash;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    RealProfile otherRealProfile = (RealProfile) obj;

    if ( gender == otherRealProfile.getGender() ){
        if ( age == otherRealProfile.getAge() ){
            if ( income == otherRealProfile.getIncome() ){
                if ( idRealProfile == otherRealProfile.getIdRealProfile() ){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что rp.hashCode() != rp3.hashCode().

Comment: @Stas0n Исправить нужно ваш подход к решению задач.

Comment: Начитался уже про hashCode, только все-равно мало что понял..

Comment: @Stas0n Это печально.

Ну попробуйте для начала сделать так, чтобы hashCode() всегда возвращал константу.

Правда contains() все равно будет возвращать false. Подумайте почему так происходит.

Comment: @a_gura, подправил метод HashCode и equal (см. выше) Там ведь сейчас все правильно?

Comment: неверно переопределен метод equals, ну то есть совсееем неверно. Почитайте про сравнение строк в java и о том какправильно переопределять equals(не помешало бы).

Comment: заменил все "==" на equals

Comment: @Stas0n: так сразу и не скажешь, но могу поспорить, вы не переопределили equals для классов `Genderё, `Age` и `Income`.

Comment: @Viacheslav, это все энумы..

Comment: @Stas0n: попробуйте поставить брейкпойнт в функции equals и оттрассируйте сравнение, увидите, вызывается ли она (вдруг вы неправильно переопределили) и почему ничего не находится.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на

```
if ( idRealProfile == otherRealProfile.getIdRealProfile() )
```

IMHO в программе `idRealProfile` вообще не устанавливается.

Но на самом деле, видимо, Вам нужен `equals`, а не `==` т.к. `==` проверяет равенство ссылок (по простому адресов), а на *содержимого* строк.